# Concise way in Scala to combine filterNot/match/case

Tags: scala

I need to filter a sequence to remove an element that matches a certain case.

This seems too clumsy:

```
val filtered = 
   headers.filterNot{ case Authorization(_) => true; case _ => false }
```

Is there a more concise/idiomatic way?

Comment: What is the type of `headers`?

Comment: `List[spray.http.HttpHeader]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isInstanceOf`, like this

```
headers.filterNot(_.isInstanceOf[Authorization])
```

Comment: Okay, in this case that works (and I will use that). But how about a more complex case, though, where I actually need to make use of the "unboxing",  like `case Authorization(Oauth2BearerToken(x)) if x.length > 5` ?

Comment: @Thilo In that case, I am afraid, there is no other way.

Comment: Using `isInstanceOf` breaks [parametricity](http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html)

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Can you explain that a bit more? Doesn't the original case class matching do the exact same thing? Is that broken as well?

Comment: That's a good question, Thilo. I encourage you to read the included typelevel blog post from S11 - http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html since he answers the question within that post.

Comment: Sorry, that article is way over my head. Can you explain what the problem with the case class matching is? Or if there is none, how `isInstanceOf` is different/worse?

Comment: What @KevinMeredith is saying is in some other languages with generic types, there is a notion of "parametricity," that a function on generics can't change its behavior based on the specific type it's called on. This restriction comes with a powerful increase in reasoning to the point where certain type signatures can only have one or a few _possible_ implementations. For example, the function `id[A](x: A): A` could only have one implementation in a language with parametricity. Sometimes you can even [automatically generate code based off types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn)!

Comment: @Thilo Scala breaks parametricity in quite a few ways. Two of them are `isInstanceOf` and case matching, both because you can change the behavior of a polymorphic function based on the type it is called on. In the latter case, this is especially obvious when using type ascriptions after variable patterns (e.g. `case a: Int => ...`), but shows up even if you don't use variable patterns because you can pattern match on subtypes. All the linked article is talking about is describing which usages of case matching don't break parametricity and how to distinguish those.

Comment: So, in the example at hand, we are safe (because the code does not change its behaviour depending on generic types, it always removes all instances of Authorization -- which is a fixed class -- from the input list)?

Comment: You are indeed "safe," although safety is ill-defined here. What you are trying to do is reasonable and easily understood. Where parametricity generally helps reasoning is when thinking about interactions among generic functions. Here there's only one and you've made it anonymous so you're not using it anywhere else; I wouldn't worry much.

If you're worried about parametricity and case matching, a good rule of thumb is if you don't have a `case _ => ...` or `case a: SomeType => ...` and your function is defined for all inputs, your function preserves parametricity.

Comment: @Thilo - please check out this excellent lecture by Prof. Brent Yorgey - http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/05-type-classes.html on parametricity. It's in Haskell, but it should be clear if you're familiar with Scala, I'd wager.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PartialFunction.cond` to omit the false case:

```
import PartialFunction.cond

headers.filterNot(cond(_) { case Authorization(_) => true } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way of doing things seems fine. Alternatively, you could take advantage of the fact that `case` statements are `PartialFunction`s and leverage that. Unfortunately, Scala's finicky type inference makes this more verbose than it should (otherwise it would be quite a nice little idiom).

```
// Ideal, but Scala's type inference lets us down and this won't compile :(
val filtered0 = headers.filterNot({ case Authorization(_) =>}.isDefinedAt) 
// This will compile, but is crazily verbose
val filtered1 = headers.filterNot(({ case Authorization(_) =>}: PartialFunction[spray.http.HttpHeader, Option[Unit]]).isDefinedAt)
```

Or you can wrap this all up in an implicit class and take care of the type signature there and leave the call-site pristine.

```
implicit class Matches[T](x: T){
  def matches(pf: PartialFunction[T, Any]) = pf isDefinedAt x
}

val filtered2 = headers filterNot (_ matches {case Authorization(_) =>})
List(Some(1), None) filterNot (_ matches {case None =>}) // List(Some(1))
```

Because this is just taking advantage of the fact that `case` statements are `PartialFunction`s, this works for arbitrary patterns.

```
List((5, 2, 'a'), (3, 4, 'b'), (3, 2, 'c')) filterNot (_ matches {case (3, _, x) if x == 'c' =>})
// List((5, 2, a), (3, 4, 'b'))
```

The `matches` idea is a minor cosmetic reworking of [Adriaan Moors' idea on the Scala mailing list](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/11252.html) debating whether to add `matches` as its own syntactic feature where the OP runs into the exact problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> sealed trait Header
defined trait Header

scala> case object Token extends Header
defined object Token

scala> case class Authorization(x: String) extends Header
defined class Authorization

scala> val headers: List[Header] = List(Token, Authorization("foo"))
headers: List[Header] = List(Token, Authorization(foo))
```

You could use `flatMap` even though it doesn't buy you anything other than `filterNot`. Although I, personally, find `flatMap` easier to understand than `filterNot` - mainly due to **my habit** of using `filter`, but not `filterNot`:

```
scala> headers.flatMap { 
     |  case Authorization(_) => Nil
     |  case other => List(other)
     | }
res1: List[Header] = List(Token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the original proposal, yet pattern matching on types,

```
headers.filter { 
  case x: Authorization => false
  case _                => true 
}
```

Another approach involves the definition of a filtering predicate,

```
def noAuth(h: Header): Boolean = h match {
  case h: Authorization => false
  case _                => true
}
```

used then for filtering,

```
headers.filter(noAuth)
```

Comment: With respect, I don't see how using `partition` with `._1` adds any value over `filterNot`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith entirely agree :) updated/trimmed answer.